# MS Access order table by order in which records were entered

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2016

I have a table in Access that I use as a progress tracker/to do list, with one field containing the date (short text) and what I did that day (long text). An example would be like this

```
date | progress
----------------
6/20 | did item1
     | tomorrow do item2 and item3
6/21 | long text I continue in the next line for visibilty
     | continued
     | to do tomorrow
6/22 | item6 completed
```

etc. I enter these things manually. the past 3 weeks or so that I have been updating this table, it opens in the same order every time -- the order in which I created the records. Recently, the table opened in a completely random order, and continues to open in that new order.

I know now that it would have been good to create an autonumber field and order it by that, or have the `date` field's default value =Now(). I ahve far to many fields to make a new ID field and manually number each record in the order I created them.

Is it at all possible to force the table to order the records in either the order I created the records, or at least the previous configuration (which was just ordered by the time created)?

Also, is there a better way to be doing this...? I want to just have a record for other people who will work with this in the future. In addition, I am new to SQL, and the Access SQl has weird/unique ways of doing things, so for some queries I know I may need in the future I keep a table with the query name and some documentation for what exactly it does and some notes about the syntax (the SQL editor does not allow for `-- comments`). Is there a better way to do this, too?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> one field containing the date (short text)

Dates should never be stored as anything else than date values. No exceptions.

So change the data type of the field to Date, sort on this, and your troubles are gone.

To order Null dates last:

```
Order By Abs([DateField] Is Null), [DateField]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you for the advice! I changed `date` to the actual Date/Time format and will make sure to keep dates with that format in the future. One of the reasons I problem is annoying though is that there are quite a few records where `date` is null (ex. table in the q)  because of the (poor) way I set this table up. When I set the OrderBy property to `date`, no matter if the datatype is Date/Time or Short Text, it puts all the records where `date` is null at the top, then the records that actually have a date at the bottom, ordered by the date.

Comment: That is correct. You can reverse the sorting of Null values - see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Specifically, my issue is that the records where `date` is null are randomly interspersed in the table, so I need to figure out how to get the order in which the records were created because that's really the only data that would order the records correctly. In the original question I have a mock table that shows the random structure of dated/empty cells.

Comment: If you had a sequential autonumber, it would most likely tell the order.